# Is there in java tool where can I show source of fresh changes on filesystem?

Tags: java, logging, filesystems

I have folder with logs. I want to realize following functionality:
output to console only fresh added log entryes.

for example at 13-00 I have launched application:
logs before 13-00 shouldn't output in console(I mean console of my read log application. it is separate application).
13-01 in `log1.txt` was written new entry(`13-01 : very important information`); - expected behavoiur - to see this entry in console.
I know about `WatchService` My knowledge that this class can only show that `log1.txt` was modified. But I want to show in console "diff" In my case it is `13-01 : very important information`

Can you advice best tool for resolving this problem?

Comment: Usually this is done with a logging library. Each such library provides the functionality to define several appenders and write log info to all of them. So your log entries are written to the file _and_ the console. You really should use such a logging library.

Comment: My problem - I want get notification about some type of logs

Comment: There are some very popular logging libraries for Java. Use your favorite web search, and you will find them. Suggesting a library is highly opinion-based. I know about _log4j_, _logback_, and even the Java integrated logging facility (_JUL_) is ok. And then their are wrappers like _Apache Commons Logging_ and _slf4j_.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have a lot of log files. Problem - configure NOTIFICATION

Comment: With a logging library you do not configure any notification mechanism. You simply write the same logging info to several destinations. Each such destination may have its own rules, what exactly to write out.

Comment: But question about notification mechanism realization

Comment: This is the reason, why I did not answer but simply put a comment. Implementing a notification mechanism is a bad idea, so I suggested a better and widely used approach.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you didn't understand me. Now my logs write to different files. I want to know moment and source when log was written.

Comment: And what prevents you from using an appender in any logging framework for exactly that purpose? We should end that discussion here, as I think, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: This question probably involves a Java application whose purpose is to aggregate logs written by other applications/daemons on the system (asker calls it a "read log application").  The Java application is not doing the logging, so Java logging frameworks are of no help here.  (And sorry to ping you on an old question.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Until now I thought that the OP has full hands on the applications in question. If so, the best approach would be to change the logging settings of these applications as this is the easiest (and a reasonable) way to achieve what he wants. It is a completely other story if we are talking about existing applications for which the OP is not responsible (and therefore cannot change the code). But this is such an important information that the OP should have explained it in the question.